# Programmatically create Linear Layout with Style

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout

I'm trying to create a `LinearLayout` programmatically but some things are just not working as expected.

This is the code:

```
LinearLayout djCard = (LinearLayout)getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.cardtemplate, null);

                    ImageView djimage = new ImageView(this);
                    djimage.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 2));
                    djimage.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
                    djimage.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_START);
                    bmpDj = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(am.open("djs/horger.jpg"));
                    djimage.setImageBitmap(bmpDj);

                    RobotoTextView djtext = new RobotoTextView(this);
                    djtext.setText(R.string.title_horger);
                    djtext.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 8));
                    djtext.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
                    djtext.setTypeface(RobotoTypefaceManager.obtaintTypeface(this,12));
                    djtext.setTextSize(R.dimen.textSizeLarge);


                    djCard.addView(djimage);
                    djCard.addView(djtext);
                    container.addView(djCard);
```

cardtemplate:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="-7dp"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    style="@style/nowCardStyle"/>
```

And look at this screenshot: The above card is what I have in xml, the other is my dynamically created card. Even the `TextView` (Custom one) is not showing...

[image: img]

This is my card layout in xml (which is what i want to have):

```
<LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/djCard1"
            style="@style/nowCardStyle"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:padding="-7dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/djImg1"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:scaleType="fitStart"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"/>

            <com.mikebdev.douala.widget.RobotoTextView
                android:id="@+id/djText1"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:typeface="roboto_condensed_light"
                android:textSize="@dimen/textSizeLarge"
                android:layout_weight="8"/>

        </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might not be the answer to your question, but it might solve you problem:

You inflate `cardtemplate.xml` with the LinearLayout, and you try to add the ImageView and RobotoTextView programmatically. 
Why don't you inflate the second XML file you provided, with the ImageView and RobotoTextView included as children and retrieve those children from the parent?

For example:

```
  ImageView djimage = (ImageView) djCard.findViewById(R.id.djImg1);
    RobotoTextView djtext = (RobotoTextView) djCard.findViewById(R.id.djText1);
```

Then you could just inflate the layout from XML, and skip the hassle with trying to create a layout programmatically :)

Comment: hm. maybe you're right. I was so fixated on doing it programmatically that i didn't even thought of that. It works better now but I still have the problem that the `Layout` with the `style` isn't properly aligned (`padding` and `margin`. Like in the screenshot above it is wider...) Any ideas on why that is?

Comment: Which layout issue do you mean? The fact that the first card has more padding/margin on the left side than the second card? You might want to use [Android's Layout Bounds tool](http://tysmith.me/post/27035355999/layoutbounds) for that.

Comment: I am using this tool but can't figure out where this issue is coming from. I have set 10dp margin on each side programmatically for now which looks accurate enough.